# ffmpeg best settings for youtube live

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this settings for ffmpeg

```bash
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://" -c:v libx264 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -preset slow -crf 18 -profile:v high -bf 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -threads 4 -cpu-used 0 -b:v 5M -r 30 -g 15 -coder 1 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"
```

but the quality and speed is not very good,
could some one tell me what at the best settings

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "[...] speed is not very good [...]"?

There are some options and combinations of options that don't make sense:

- Since you are using `-crf`, replace `-b:v 5M` with `-maxrate 5M -bufsize 10M`

  See [Constrained encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#ConstrainedencodingVBVmaximumbitrate) for more info.
- Delete `-movflags +faststart`. This option is useful when you output an `.mp4` and want to optimize the file for progressive download.

```bash
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://" \
-c:v libx264 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -preset slow -crf 18 \
-profile:v high -bf 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-threads 4 -cpu-used 0 \
-maxrate 5M -bufsize 10M -r 30 -g 15 -coder 1 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"
```